# C# Export Private/Public RSA key from RSACryptoServiceProvider to PEM string

Tags: c#, cryptography, rsa, pem

I have an instance of System.Security.Cryptography.RSACryptoServiceProvider, i need to export it's key to a PEM string - like this:

```
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----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-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```

But there is no such option according to the MSDN documentation, there is only some kind of XML export. I can't use any third party libraries like BouncyCastle.
Is there any way to generate this string?

Comment: How and where does an instance of that class have a key?

Comment: Tthe pain point is due to .Net and their use of XML encoding from [RFC 3275](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3275.txt). .Net does not use ASN.1/DER or PEM encoded keys. I think its the only crypto library that does things this way.

Answer (score 94, accepted):

**Please note: The code below is for exporting a *private* key. If you are looking to export the *public* key, please refer to my answer given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28406888/c-sharp-rsa-public-key-output-not-correct/28407693#28407693).**

The PEM format is simply the [ASN.1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_Syntax_Notation_One) DER encoding of the key (per [PKCS#1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3447#section-3.2)) converted to Base64. Given the limited number of fields needed to represent the key, it's pretty straightforward to create quick-and-dirty DER encoder to output the appropriate format then Base64 encode it. As such, the code that follows is not particularly elegant, but does the job:

```
private static void ExportPrivateKey(RSACryptoServiceProvider csp, TextWriter outputStream)
{
    if (csp.PublicOnly) throw new ArgumentException("CSP does not contain a private key", "csp");
    var parameters = csp.ExportParameters(true);
    using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        var writer = new BinaryWriter(stream);
        writer.Write((byte)0x30); // SEQUENCE
        using (var innerStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            var innerWriter = new BinaryWriter(innerStream);
            EncodeIntegerBigEndian(innerWriter, new byte[] { 0x00 }); // Version
            EncodeIntegerBigEndian(innerWriter, parameters.Modulus);
            EncodeIntegerBigEndian(innerWriter, parameters.Exponent);
            EncodeIntegerBigEndian(innerWriter, parameters.D);
            EncodeIntegerBigEndian(innerWriter, parameters.P);
            EncodeIntegerBigEndian(innerWriter, parameters.Q);
            EncodeIntegerBigEndian(innerWriter, parameters.DP);
            EncodeIntegerBigEndian(innerWriter, parameters.DQ);
            EncodeIntegerBigEndian(innerWriter, parameters.InverseQ);
            var length = (int)innerStream.Length;
            EncodeLength(writer, length);
            writer.Write(innerStream.GetBuffer(), 0, length);
        }

        var base64 = Convert.ToBase64String(stream.GetBuffer(), 0, (int)stream.Length).ToCharArray();
        outputStream.WriteLine("-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----");
        // Output as Base64 with lines chopped at 64 characters
        for (var i = 0; i < base64.Length; i += 64)
        {
            outputStream.WriteLine(base64, i, Math.Min(64, base64.Length - i));
        }
        outputStream.WriteLine("-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----");
    }
}

private static void EncodeLength(BinaryWriter stream, int length)
{
    if (length < 0) throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("length", "Length must be non-negative");
    if (length < 0x80)
    {
        // Short form
        stream.Write((byte)length);
    }
    else
    {
        // Long form
        var temp = length;
        var bytesRequired = 0;
        while (temp > 0)
        {
            temp >>= 8;
            bytesRequired++;
        }
        stream.Write((byte)(bytesRequired | 0x80));
        for (var i = bytesRequired - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            stream.Write((byte)(length >> (8 * i) & 0xff));
        }
    }
}

private static void EncodeIntegerBigEndian(BinaryWriter stream, byte[] value, bool forceUnsigned = true)
{
    stream.Write((byte)0x02); // INTEGER
    var prefixZeros = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < value.Length; i++)
    {
        if (value[i] != 0) break;
        prefixZeros++;
    }
    if (value.Length - prefixZeros == 0)
    {
        EncodeLength(stream, 1);
        stream.Write((byte)0);
    }
    else
    {
        if (forceUnsigned && value[prefixZeros] > 0x7f)
        {
            // Add a prefix zero to force unsigned if the MSB is 1
            EncodeLength(stream, value.Length - prefixZeros + 1);
            stream.Write((byte)0);
        }
        else
        {
            EncodeLength(stream, value.Length - prefixZeros);
        }
        for (var i = prefixZeros; i < value.Length; i++)
        {
            stream.Write(value[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Great, this works perfectly, but how do I export the public key. Does it have similar structure. I've tried doing this with just the exponent and modulus (the contents of the public key) but it doesn't return a valid result. How to get the public key string?

Comment: Never mind. I got it working, I forgot to remove the version part. Now it also exports public keys.

Comment: For those interested, correctly exporting a public key can be done via the code in my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28406888/c-sharp-rsa-public-key-output-not-correct/28407693#28407693 which re-uses some of the methods from this answer.

Comment: This works great for exporting both private key and public key to `pem` file

Comment: @RijulSudhir if you're exporting the public key, you should use the code given in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28406888/c-sharp-rsa-public-key-output-not-correct/28407693#28407693

Comment: @Iridium I tried the code in that link first. But it didn't work.File is created. But decryption using that key file fails. But decryption using public key exported with `ExportPrivateKey` function worked fine for me.

Comment: @RijulSudhir if you're decrypting a file, you need the private key (exported by the code above), not a public key.

Comment: @Iridium I think you misunderstood what I wrote. Any way, for me export function `ExportPrivateKey` worked perfectly for both private and public key. I wanted anyone who may read this answer to know about that. That is why I commented in the first place. So that they can also try it if everything else fails in case of exporting public key.

Comment: I've compiled and slightly modified Iridium's two excellent export functions and combined them with import functions for a full solution (import and export both public and private keys):

[Import and export RSA Keys between C# and PEM format using BouncyCastle](https://gist.github.com/therightstuff/aa65356e95f8d0aae888e9f61aa29414)

Answer (score 18):

With the current version of .NET, this can be done in a simple way.

```cs
  RSA rsa = RSA.Create();
  rsa.KeySize = 4096;

  // Private key export.
  string hdrPrv = "-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----";
  string ftrPrv = "-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----";
  string keyPrv = Convert.ToBase64String(rsa.ExportPkcs8PrivateKey());
  string PEMPrv = $"{hdrPrv}\n{keyPrv}\n{ftrPrv}";//concatenate header and footer to actual key


  // Public key export (with a correction for more accuracy from RobSiklos's comment to have the key in PKCS#1 RSAPublicKey format)
  string hdrPub = "-----BEGIN RSA PUBLIC KEY-----";
  string ftrPub = "-----END RSA PUBLIC KEY-----";
  string keyPub = Convert.ToBase64String(rsa.ExportRSAPublicKey());
  string PEMPub = $"{hdrPub}\n{keyPub}\n{ftrPub}";//concatenate header and footer to actual key
  
  // Distribute PEMs.
```

Note: To have the nicely formatted file with new lines, you can write a little function to do it for you.
With the solution given above, you will have a file with only three lines.

Comment: In your comment for exporting public key you say to use hdr and ftr but those values are specific to the private key....  should be hdr="-----BEGIN RSA PUBLIC KEY-----" and ftr="-----END RSA PUBLIC KEY-----"

Comment: perhaps I wrote this bad, but saying `update hdr and ftr` in meant exactly what you said. :)

Comment: This is slightly incorrect. When using `ExportSubjectPublicKeyInfo()` the header/footer should contain "PUBLIC KEY" not "RSA PUBLIC KEY". If you want to use the latter, then use `ExportRSAPublicKey()` instead of `ExportSubjectPublicKeyInfo()`

Answer (score 12):

If you're using .NET Core 3.0 this is already implemented out of the box

```
    public string ExportPrivateKey(RSA rsa)
    {
        var privateKeyBytes = rsa.ExportRSAPrivateKey();
        var builder = new StringBuilder("-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY");
        builder.AppendLine("-----");

        var base64PrivateKeyString = Convert.ToBase64String(privateKeyBytes);
        var offset = 0;
        const int LINE_LENGTH = 64;

        while (offset < base64PrivateKeyString.Length)
        {
            var lineEnd = Math.Min(offset + LINE_LENGTH, base64PrivateKeyString.Length);
            builder.AppendLine(base64PrivateKeyString.Substring(offset, lineEnd - offset));
            offset = lineEnd;
        }

        builder.Append("-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY");
        builder.AppendLine("-----");
        return builder.ToString();
    }
```

Comment: This code worked just fine for me - BUT is has a small bug: The opening line states "BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY" (which is correct), but the closing line omits the "RSA" -> closing line should be "END RSA PRIVATE KEY"

Comment: Hi @Prasanth, can you please share the details about where it is pointed that RSACryptoServiceProvider in .NET Core is Windows specific?

Comment: I think, RSACryptoServiceProvider is not windows specific. Windows CSP (CAPI) is windows specific. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.rsacryptoserviceprovider?view=net-6.0

Answer (score 7):

Here is a **GREAT NEWS**, with **.NET 7**, Microsoft has added a new method to export RSA keys directly to PEM format.

Refer [RSA.ExportRSAPrivateKeyPem Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.rsa.exportrsaprivatekeypem)

Below is how you can use it.

```
using (var rsa = new RSACryptoServiceProvider(2048)) // Generate a new 2048 bit RSA key
{
    // RSA keys in PKCS#1 format, PEM encoded
    string publicPrivateKeyPEM = rsa.ExportRSAPrivateKeyPem();
    string publicOnlyKeyPEM = rsa.ExportRSAPublicKeyPem();

    // RSA keys in XML format
    string publicPrivateKeyXML = rsa.ToXmlString(true);
    string publicOnlyKeyXML = rsa.ToXmlString(false);

    // RSA keys in byte array
    byte[] publicPrivateKey = rsa.ExportRSAPrivateKey();
    byte[] publicOnlyKey = rsa.ExportRSAPublicKey();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

For anyone else who balked at the original answer's apparent complexity (which is very helpful, don't get me wrong), I thought I'd post my solution which is a little more straightforward IMO (but still based on the original answer):

```
public class RsaCsp2DerConverter {
   private const int MaximumLineLength = 64;

   // Based roughly on: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23739932/1254575

   public RsaCsp2DerConverter() {

   }

   public byte[] ExportPrivateKey(String cspBase64Blob) {
      if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(cspBase64Blob) == true)
         throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(cspBase64Blob));

      var csp = new RSACryptoServiceProvider();

      csp.ImportCspBlob(Convert.FromBase64String(cspBase64Blob));

      if (csp.PublicOnly)
         throw new ArgumentException("CSP does not contain a private key!", nameof(csp));

      var parameters = csp.ExportParameters(true);

      var list = new List<byte[]> {
         new byte[] {0x00},
         parameters.Modulus,
         parameters.Exponent,
         parameters.D,
         parameters.P,
         parameters.Q,
         parameters.DP,
         parameters.DQ,
         parameters.InverseQ
      };

      return SerializeList(list);
   }

   private byte[] Encode(byte[] inBytes, bool useTypeOctet = true) {
      int length = inBytes.Length;
      var bytes = new List<byte>();

      if (useTypeOctet == true)
         bytes.Add(0x02); // INTEGER

      bytes.Add(0x84); // Long format, 4 bytes
      bytes.AddRange(BitConverter.GetBytes(length).Reverse());
      bytes.AddRange(inBytes);

      return bytes.ToArray();
   }

   public String PemEncode(byte[] bytes) {
      if (bytes == null)
         throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(bytes));

      var base64 = Convert.ToBase64String(bytes);

      StringBuilder b = new StringBuilder();
      b.Append("-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----\n");

      for (int i = 0; i < base64.Length; i += MaximumLineLength)
         b.Append($"{ base64.Substring(i, Math.Min(MaximumLineLength, base64.Length - i)) }\n");

      b.Append("-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----\n");

      return b.ToString();
   }

   private byte[] SerializeList(List<byte[]> list) {
      if (list == null)
         throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(list));

      var keyBytes = list.Select(e => Encode(e)).SelectMany(e => e).ToArray();

      var binaryWriter = new BinaryWriter(new MemoryStream());
      binaryWriter.Write((byte) 0x30); // SEQUENCE
      binaryWriter.Write(Encode(keyBytes, false));
      binaryWriter.Flush();

      var result = ((MemoryStream) binaryWriter.BaseStream).ToArray();

      binaryWriter.BaseStream.Dispose();
      binaryWriter.Dispose();

      return result;
   }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
 public static Func<string, string> ToBase64PemFromKeyXMLString= (xmlPrivateKey) =>
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(xmlPrivateKey))
                throw new ArgumentNullException("RSA key must contains value!");
            var keyContent = new PemReader(new StringReader(xmlPrivateKey));
            if (keyContent == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("private key is not valid!");
            var ciphrPrivateKey = (AsymmetricCipherKeyPair)keyContent.ReadObject();
            var asymmetricKey = new AsymmetricKeyEntry(ciphrPrivateKey.Private);

            PrivateKeyInfo privateKeyInfo = PrivateKeyInfoFactory.CreatePrivateKeyInfo(asymmetricKey.Key);
            var serializedPrivateKey = privateKeyInfo.ToAsn1Object().GetDerEncoded();
            return Convert.ToBase64String(serializedPrivateKey);
        };
```