# How to Generate RSA Public Key from Modulus and Exponent in Swift 4?

Tags: ios, swift, swift4

I need to generate RSA Public Key from Modulus and Exponent. I am new about Swift so I searched about that. I found these:

[Generate RSA Public Key from Modulus and Exponent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29669858/generate-rsa-public-key-from-modulus-and-exponent)

[Generating public key from modulus and exponent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40607576/generating-public-key-from-modulus-and-exponent)

https://meniny.cn/posts/RSA_public_key_with_modulus_and_exponent/

But this suggestions are not compiled with Swift 4. there are so much errors. Also I found this : https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/4866

it said "iOS does not provide any public APIs for this". so how can I do this ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Generating public key from modulus and exponent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40607576/generating-public-key-from-modulus-and-exponent)

Comment: @EneaDume, you can find this url in my question. the answer is not compiled in Swift 4

Comment: you're a developer, man. If the solution was in swift 3 it doesn't make a lot of difference in swift 4. you must try something yourself

Comment: @EneaDume can you please show me Swift 3 solution ?

Comment: Which class or struct do you use to store the modulus, same question for the exponent? Which class or struct do you want to store the public key? Last question: can you please give some code you wrote to answer the question and tell which part doesn't work or return an error.