# RSAParameters fields sizes?

Tags: c#

I create asymmetric key pair via `RSACryptoServiceProvider` . I get the key pair in `byte[]`, so it can be saved. I'm avoiding the XML option, in order to avoid possible cross-platform encoding issues.

```
        public byte[] CreateKeyPair()
    {
        RSACryptoServiceProvider rsa = new RSACryptoServiceProvider();

        //read the key pair in byte[]
        RSAParameters rsaKeyPair = rsa.ExportParameters(true);
        List<byte> keyPairList = new List<byte>();
        foreach (byte b in rsaKeyPair.D) { keyPairList.Add(b); }
        foreach (byte b in rsaKeyPair.DP) { keyPairList.Add(b); }
        foreach (byte b in rsaKeyPair.DQ) { keyPairList.Add(b); }
        foreach (byte b in rsaKeyPair.Exponent) { keyPairList.Add(b); }
        foreach (byte b in rsaKeyPair.InverseQ) { keyPairList.Add(b); }
        foreach (byte b in rsaKeyPair.Modulus) { keyPairList.Add(b); }
        foreach (byte b in rsaKeyPair.P) { keyPairList.Add(b); }
        foreach (byte b in rsaKeyPair.Q) { keyPairList.Add(b); }

        return keyPairList.ToArray();
    }
```

now I want to convert from `byte[]` back to `RSACryptoServiceProvider`.

My question is, are all the fields of fixed size every time, and if so what size is each field, or should I delimit those somehow?

What if I serialize `RSAParameters` , will someone be able to easily deserialize/read the struct in C++? I think not, but worth asking anyway...

Comment: Use a know format like PEM/DER? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23734792/c-sharp-export-private-public-rsa-key-from-rsacryptoserviceprovider-to-pem-strin

Comment: this looks very ugly, like shooting a fly with ak47 :)

Comment: The AK47 is famous for being reliable and easily maintainable.