# MemoryStream does not contain a definition for GetBuffer()

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, stream, buffer

I've started working with C# and .NET Core and I'm trying to implement the code in the answer at https://stackoverflow.com/a/23739932/1459684

However, I have a problem with lines 
`writer.Write(innerStream.GetBuffer(), 0, length);` 
and 
`var base64 = Convert.ToBase64String(stream.GetBuffer(), 0, (int)stream.Length).ToCharArray();` 
where the method `getBuffer()` no longer appears to be available. I receive the error:

> "'MemoryStream' does not contain a definition for 'GetBuffer' and no extension method 'GetBuffer' accepting a first argument of type 'MemoryStream' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"

With a Google the only other instance of this seems to be at https://github.com/hultqvist/ProtoBuf/issues/35 but does not give me an indication of what refactoring I should make.

Comment: @mjwills Yes it did thank you. I should've read more carefully, I saw that `TryGetBuffer` returns a boolean and so assumed it was not what I needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rather than `GetBuffer` you need to use [`TryGetBuffer`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.memorystream.trygetbuffer(v=vs.110).aspx).

See https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/1897 for more details.