# MemoryStream library does not contain GetBuffer method

Tags: c#, uwp

I am developing a portable dll to use in uwp app. but MemoryStream library does not contain GetBuffer() method. also there is no TryGetBuffer() method either.

P.S. I checked the answer in following link but as i said there is no TryGetBuffer() method, too.

[MemoryStream does not contain a definition for GetBuffer()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45282478/memorystream-does-not-contain-a-definition-for-getbuffer)

Comment: Are you sure what you are looking for is not *ToArray*

Comment: I read that GetBuffer() is faster than ToArray() and speed is important in my project

Comment: `GetBuffer!=ToArray` http://invalidlogic.com/2006/03/13/dangers-of-memorystream-getbuffer/

Comment: BTW: `speed is important in my project`, if you really need that small speedup in your project, I can say that you are in trouble...

Comment: I read it and thank you i will use ToArray