# .Net Standard 2.0 RSA.ExportParameters(bool) not working on Linux

Tags: cryptography, rsa, .net-standard-2.0

Have implemented some https support infrastructure. In one place need to Convert RSA to pem format. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23734792/c-sharp-export-private-public-rsa-key-from-rsacryptoserviceprovider-to-pem-strin/23739932) found the solution, that works fine on Windows, but as soon as run it in docker with linux, after the construction

`var parameters = rsa.ExportParameters(true);` have got next error

```
System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException Cannot open an invalid handle. Void CheckInvalidKey(Microsoft.Win32.SafeHandles.SafeRsaHandle)
```

Is there any alternative to export RSA in pem format ?  If not is there any alternative way to get parameters from RSA ?

Comment: There are always alternatives, but we'd need to know why you are trying to export it in "PEM" format (which is not really a format after all). Knowing more about the requirements of the software that will be consuming this "PEM" private key would be a good start.

Comment: Where did you get the RSA object, did you perhaps already dispose it?

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I've tested it's not disposed and It works on Windows OS. @JamesKPolk thanks for your question. Other components that consume the result of the method I've written expect to see "PEM" format. It's clear that it's not a format like X509 it's just a plain text with Header Base64 and footer, and the algorithm I've found to Convert pvk by the link above looks very complicated and by some steps ( some deltas seems to supports some legacy requirements.  Will be appreciated if you can suggest some better to support format to export private RSA key workable in .Net Standard!

Comment: More strange thing I've found that the same code instruction var parameters = rsa.ExportParameters(true);  works fine even on Linux if it's inside .Net Core. Seems it's issue more related to understanding the difference of compilation .Net Core and .Net Standard project.

Comment: @ВиталийАйрапетян There shouldn't be any difference, but if you can come up with a sharable repro, please open an issue at https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/.